# Increase line width of coloured line without introducing wiggles ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to colour a line by the value of the y-axis while also increasing its width in ggplot. However, when I increase the width this introduces wiggles along the line.
[image: 1]

Reproducible example

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = seq(-3, 2.99, by = .01))
df$y <- dnorm(df$x)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = y )) + 
  geom_line(size = 10)
```

If I don't colour by `y` it displays a smooth curve, I only have this issue when colouring by the y-axis value.

Similarly, if I remove the `size` parameter it displays just fine, except it is too thin. Is there a way to have a thick AND smooth curve?

Comment: Not reproducible.  When I run your code, I get a thick line shaded according to the value of `y`.

Comment: I get the same issue as @Delete with "R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)", "RStudio - Version 1.4.1106" working in Windows with `ggplot2` v3.3.5,

Comment: @Limey what R version/platform are you on? Similar to Peter, I am on windows 10, R version 4.0.3 and RStudio version 1.4.1106

Comment: @Peter "R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)", R Studio Version 1.4.1717, ggplot2 v3.3.5. macOS Mojave 10.14.6.  Delete: Even though it's not an "answer" would you like me to post the plot I get to confirm it's what you want/expect?

Comment: @Limey - its not my question - I just thought to check it out on my computer and curiously get exactly the same graph as the OP, even after I've updated RStudio to version 1.4.1717.  I tried with base R graphics and that worked fine: `plot(df, "l", col = "red", lwd = 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the same reproducible example with:

In Arch Linux

R version: 4.1.1

RStudio: 1.4.1106

tidyverse: 1.3.1

ggplot2: 3.3.5

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = seq(-3, 2.99, by = .01))
df$y <- dnorm(df$x)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = y )) + 
  geom_line(size = 10)
```

Output:[image]